# What is the purpose of session.endConversation()

Tags: botframework

I am developing a bot in node.js using the Microsoft Bot Framework. Once my user has completed their action with my bot; I am calling `session.endConversation()`. However, I am not sure really what this is doing. My assumption when calling this code would be that it would clear out session data; so if the user interacts with the bot again; they will essentially be starting over.

However, when I call endConversation(), the user data is still there:

```
    session.endConversation("Thank you for your business!");
    console.log("User Data:");
    console.log(session.userData);
```

[image]

The [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#endconversation) just says, "ends the conversation" but doesn't describe what in fact that means.

I guess my question is; what is this function doing and when you are finished with a conversation, what should the approach be to handle the users conversation data?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323113634/http://blog.geektrainer.com/2017/02/21/Managing-conversations-and-dialogs-in-Microsoft-Bot-Framework-using-Node-JS/):

As a result, when a conversation or dialog has come to an end, it’s a best practice to explicitly call `endConversation`, `endDialog`, or `endDialogWithResult`. `endConversation` both clears the current dialog stack and resets all data stored in the session, ***except userData***. Both `endDialog` and `endDialogWithResult` end the dialog, clear out dialogData, and control to previous dialog in the stack. Unlike `endDialog`, `endDialogWithResult` allows you to pass arguments into the previous dialog, which will be available in the second parameter of the first method in the waterfall (typically named results).